# memalign not defined in Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, malloc

I'm interested if anyone has managed to port [HCRF2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hcrf/) to Mac OS X. I get stuck when building a cpp file using *malloc.h*. Apparently this is a deprecated package and there's not a whole lot out there telling you how to port programs using it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not a C++ man.

```
[  2%] Building CXX object hCRF/CMakeFiles/hCRF.dir/src/matrixSSE2.cpp.o
/Volumes/LocalScratchHD/LocalHome/savkov/Software/HCRF2.0b/libs/shared/hCRF/src/matrixSSE2.cpp:9:10: error: 'malloc.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <malloc.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     "malloc.h"
/Volumes/LocalScratchHD/LocalHome/savkov/Software/HCRF2.0b/libs/shared/hCRF/src/matrixSSE2.cpp:89:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'memalign'
            pData = (double*)memalign(16, size*sizeof(double));
                             ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [hCRF/CMakeFiles/hCRF.dir/src/matrixSSE2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [hCRF/CMakeFiles/hCRF.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

UPDATE:

I copied malloc.h into the source folder and things went a bit further. Now I get another error:

```
/.../HCRF2.0b/libs/shared/hCRF/src/matrixSSE2.cpp: In member function 'void Matrix<elType>::create(int, int, elType) [with elType = double]':
/.../HCRF2.0b/libs/shared/hCRF/src/matrixSSE2.cpp:89:52: error: 'memalign' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: This is question 255555.  _It's just so beautiful!_

Comment: Please post the error message and we'll start there.

Comment: What toolchain are you using to compile this?  `#include <malloc.h>` should work everywhere (within reason).

Comment: I use cmake to prepare the make files and then make if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, I want to know the compiler you are using.  Is it the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: Initially the system was set to use Xcode (gcc4.2), then I tried setting the compiler manually to gcc4.8 when starting cmake. Both didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

OSX lacks `memalign()`, but it *does* have `posix_memalign()`.  It has a different signature than `memalign()`, so you'll have to tweak the sources a bit.  Where you have:

```
pData = (double*)memalign(16, size*sizeof(double));
```

you can re-write that as (untested):

```
err = posix_memalign((void **)&pData, 16, size*sizeof(double));
```

But I believe that OSX always allocates on 16 byte boundaries.  If this is the case, you can just as easily use `malloc()`:

```
pData = (double *)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
```

(If you go this route, it would be wise to include an assertion that verifies pData to be on a 16 byte boundary.)